# How do sites like Facebook force users to load newly released version?

Tags: browser

Browsers do cache a lot of JS and CSS files. How do sites like Facebook work around this issue whenever they release new production code? Do they do cache busting to do this in all their resources? I do see these jumbled up characters in all their image files at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generaly what they do add a version number or some unique code at the end of java script urls in the html file like

http://your_js_url?v=2

whenever there is a new version they just change the v=2 to v=3 that refreshes all user browser cache

Same for css url

Comment: I don't see those query strings. Instead they seem to use some hashed values right in the resource names. Given the traffic that they get, I would guess they put these hashed file names during build time rather than interrupting individual HTTP requests and replace strings before responding?

Comment: There are multiple way.. this is the most common way... and you do not have to replace string in every page.. they create constant at property files which is read by php or server side code and auto populate the value in url when page load

Comment: But things like profile images would have to come from database because you don't know how often a user might update that right?

Comment: Definitely.. that will come from database everytime the page loads.

Comment: Those constants in property files would have to be generated during build time right? Because the developers will not be able to remember those file names.

Comment: But you can cache that as well.. if you just save the image in database with a unique hash name and continue that name while giving back the image to ui.. It will cache it and when user change that just change the hash name and that will force the load

Comment: Yes. In build time they have to update the constant... its like a build version